# How to mark a question as solved on Stackoverflow

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Once you have asked a question on Stackoverflow and had feedback that solved the question how do I mark the question as solved so that the contributer gets due credit?

Comment: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Thanks for asking, rather than just leaving the answers unaccepted!

Comment: You **definitely do not** put something like "SOLVED" in the title, nor do you edit your question with "SOLVED".  You add an *answer* just like everyone else and then accept *that* answer.